# How to connect container by IP in Azure VM on Node.js project?

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, deployment, port

**Task**:
Deploy the project to Azure VM cloud.

**Steps**:

- Created an instance and installed docker on the instance.
- There is no firewall or network security groups, I've selected none on network security settings while creating instance.
- I have 2 containers as web client and grafana, website using node js.

**Problem**:
The website shows `grafana` in a div. Defined grafana's address as `localhost:3001` on my local but when I started project on VM and try to load the site from my local pc, grafana's div is not loading.

**More Info**:

[image: Click here to image]

Website tries to connect localhost on my pc, I need to write AzureVM's Grafana Containers IP address but I don't have an idea about what to do.

[image: Click here to image]

Comment: Any updates for the question? I didn't any response. Do you still work on it? Or you just do want to get the solution without response?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change the listening URL into `https://0.0.0.0:3001`. The `localhost` always is used to access the application inside the VM and it cannot be accessible outside the VM.